# Как узнать, сколько юзер прошел за определенный скролл страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно узнать значение того, сколько юзер прошел за определенный скролл расстояния и записать это значение в переменную?

Comment: Т.е. нужна позиция прокрутка в данный момент? Или, например, разница между прокруткой от 200 пикселей до 400 пикселей? Нужна именно этот разность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто используй `$(document).scrollTop()` и плагин jquery-mousewheel (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel)

```
var lastScrollPosition = 0, scrollDistance;

$('body').mousewheel(function() {
  clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
  $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
    scrollDistance = $(document).scrollTop() - lastScrollPosition;
    lastScrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
    console.log(scrollDistance);
  }, 250));
});
```

Мой пример на CodePen(здесть плагин не работает почему-то): https://codepen.io/Rundik/pen/OjrBNK

Вот две темы на английском stackoverflow, откуда я взял инфу: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021440/detect-distance-scrolled-from-top-jquery
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308987/catch-one-scroll

Comment: Требуется, на сколько я понимаю, дистанция одного скролла, а не текущее положение скролла

Comment: понял, исправлю